# Flag Varieties - Projective Curves

Tags: projective-geometry, flags

Is it true that there are no projective curves which are also flag manifolds? If so, why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The projective line is both a curve of genus $0$ and a flag variety for $SL_2$. This is the only example. This is true for about a zillion reasons:

Flag varieties are rational (because of the Bruhat decomposition.) Curves, of genus $>0$, are not.

Flag varieties have transitive group actions. Curves of genus $\geq 2$ do not (see my answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3296/projective-curves-which-are-principal-bundles/3301#3301).)

If you look at the classification of flag varieties, there are only finitely many of any given dimension. In paritcular, there is only one example of dimension $1$.

Comment: I'm having a little trouble phrasing this politely: What definition of flag variety do you know, and what definition of projective line, so that it is not clear that the projective line is an example of a flag variety?

Answer (score 0):

According to this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_flag_variety

"Flag varieties are naturally projective varieties."

Comment: Yes, I've seen this. But my question is whether they are projective CURVES.